# How can I fix my Ubuntu 19.10 system failing to boot due to "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device"?

Tags: boot, 19.10

a couple days ago, my Ubuntu laptop would fail to resume after being put to sleep. No big deal, I thought, I'll just power it on each time.  Today however, I noticed my laptop was taking almost 5 minutes to boot. I went to see what it was doing, and it simply says `Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device.` Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix it?

Comment: You can look at the logs of the current boot by `sudo journalctl -b 0`, and get more information, like what is starting whatever issued that message. Install the `pm-utils` package and read `man pm-is-supported`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `free -h`.